# Using Key Listeners to change a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, keylistener

I am making a simple Snake game and everything seems to be working except the Key Listener.  Based on everything I am seeing it is written correctly.

The game shows up but the Snake just does not move even if you press on the Arrow Keys.

Thanks in advance!

This is the Main:

```
    public class SnakeFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int direction;
    private World w;
    private WorldComponant wc;
    GameLoopThread glt;

    public SnakeFrame(){
        setSize(420,440);
        setTitle("Snake");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        w = new World();
        wc = new WorldComponant(w);
        glt = new GameLoopThread(wc);
        direction = Direction.SOUTH;

        c.add(wc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SnakeFrame s = new SnakeFrame();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case (KeyEvent.VK_UP):{
            if(direction!=Direction.SOUTH){
                direction = Direction.NORTH;
                wc.move(direction);
            }
            break;
        }
        case (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN):{
            if(direction!=Direction.NORTH){
                direction = Direction.SOUTH;
                wc.move(direction);
            }
            break;
        }
        case (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT):{
            if(direction!=Direction.WEST){
                direction = Direction.EAST;
                wc.move(direction);
            }
            break;
        }
        case (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT):{
            if(direction!=Direction.EAST){
                direction = Direction.WEST;
                wc.move(direction);
            }
            break;
        }
        }
}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

This is the GameLoopThread:

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread{

    private WorldComponant sc;

    public GameLoopThread(WorldComponant sc){
        this.sc = sc;
    }



    public void run(){
        while(true){
            sc.repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the move method.  It is inside the World Class and called from a WorldComponant also:

```
public void move(int direction) {
        Point head = snake.peekFirst();
        Point newPt = head;
        switch(direction){
        case (Direction.NORTH):{
            newPt = new Point(head.x, head.y-1);
            break;
        }
        case (Direction.SOUTH):{
            newPt = new Point(head.x, head.y+1);
            break;
        }
        case (Direction.WEST):{
            newPt = new Point(head.x-1, head.y);
            break;
        }
        case (Direction.EAST):{
            newPt = new Point(head.x+1, head.y);
            break;
        }

        }

        snake.remove(snake.peekLast());

        if(newPt.equals(food)){
            Point addPt = (Point) newPt.clone(); 

            switch(direction){
            case (Direction.NORTH):{
                newPt = new Point(head.x, head.y-1);
                break;
            }
            case (Direction.SOUTH):{
                newPt = new Point(head.x, head.y+1);
                break;
            }
            case (Direction.WEST):{
                newPt = new Point(head.x-1, head.y);
                break;
            }
            case (Direction.EAST):{
                newPt = new Point(head.x+1, head.y);
                break;
            }

            }
            score++;
            snake.add(addPt);
            placeFood();

        }
        else if(newPt.x < 0 || newPt.x > gridw - 1){
            generateDefaultSnake();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU LOST! :(", "Loser!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        else if(newPt.y < 0 || newPt.y > gridh - 1){
            generateDefaultSnake();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU LOST! :(", "Loser!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        else if(snake.contains(newPt)){
            generateDefaultSnake();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU LOST! :(", "Loser!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        snake.add(newPt);

    }
```

Comment: Do you ever add the implemented keylistener to your JFrame? On another note, if your WorldComponant class hapens to be a subclass of `JComponent`, you should consider using key bindings.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener! See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for the better approach of using `Key Bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setFocusable(true)` and `requestFocusInWindow()` on your `JFrame` after you have made the `JFrame` visible.  (Although, I think setFocusable(true) isn't necessary for JFrames).

[How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

[How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListerner` is well know for been troublesome, but is even worse when trying to add them directly to a `JFrame`. A `JFrame` has a `JRootPane`, `contentPane` and possibly a `glassPane` between it and the user all of which could steal focus and prevent the `KeyListener` from receiving key events.

A better solution would be to use the key bindings api and register it against a custom contentPane

See [How to use key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details